# Как автоматически масштабировать график

Tags: python, matplotlib

У точки `Q` координат `[7,17]`. Как сделать чтобы `plot` автоматом масштабировался(зуммировался)? На маленьких координатах все отлично. Также я вижу что что график кривой и прямой ограничены размером холста `(10,10)`

```
y, x =  np.mgrid[-10:10:100j, -10:10:100j]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы привели невоспроизводимый программно вопрос - получите такой-же ответ:

В Matplotlib есть методы set_xlim и set_ylim, первый параметр которых -  список из двух элементов, определяющих желаемый диапазон отображаемых на графике значений. Вот ими как раз и управляют "зуммированием" - устанавливая по координатам минимальные (или близкие к ним) значения х и y.